# How to add elements to an array created by a 'for' loop ?

Tags: iphone

I am using for loop for get distance from current location to destination location. I would like an array that contains all distances from current to destination location.

```
for (i = 0; i < [Arr_Lat count]; i++)  
{
    NSString *latst1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:[Arr_Lat objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *longst1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:[Arr_Long objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSLog(@"First lat : %@",latst1);
    NSLog(@"First  ong : %@",longst1);

    double Doblat1 = [latst1 doubleValue];
    double Doblong1 = [longst1 doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord1.latitude = Doblat1, coord1.longitude = Doblat1);

    NSLog(@" Coordinat ==== : %f -- %f",coord1.latitude,coord1.longitude) ;

    CLLocation *currLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDel.curr_lat longitude:appDel.curr_long];

    CLLocation *destLoc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Doblat1 longitude:Doblong1];

    NSLog(@" Currennt Location : %@", currLoc);
    NSLog(@" Destination Location : %@" , destLoc1);

    distance = [destLoc1  distanceFromLocation:currLoc];

    NSLog(@" Distance  :   ------- %0.3f", distance);

    DistStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" %f",distance];

    [currLoc release];

    [destLoc1 release];
    [Arr_title retain];

    [tbl_nearplace reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *Distance=[[NSMutableArray alloc]Init];

for (i = 0; i < [Arr_Lat count]; i++)  
{
    NSString *latst1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:[Arr_Lat objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *longst1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:[Arr_Long objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSLog(@"First lat : %@",latst1);
    NSLog(@"First  ong : %@",longst1);

    double Doblat1 = [latst1 doubleValue];
    double Doblong1 = [longst1 doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord1.latitude = Doblat1, coord1.longitude = Doblat1);

    NSLog(@" Coordinat ==== : %f -- %f",coord1.latitude,coord1.longitude) ;

    CLLocation *currLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDel.curr_lat longitude:appDel.curr_long];

    CLLocation *destLoc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Doblat1 longitude:Doblong1];

    NSLog(@" Currennt Location : %@", currLoc);
    NSLog(@" Destination Location : %@" , destLoc1);

    distance = [destLoc1  distanceFromLocation:currLoc];

    NSLog(@" Distance  :   ------- %0.3f", distance);

    NSString *DistStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" %f",distance];

    [Distance addObject:DistStr];

    [DistStr release];
    [currLoc release];

    [destLoc1 release];
    [Arr_title retain];

    [tbl_nearplace reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the distance you need an NSMutableArray.

1. Declare a `NSMutableArray *distanceArray;` in class scope.
2. Initialize it: distanceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
3. In the for loop after `DistStr =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" %f",distance];`
   write the following code:

   ```
   [distanceArray addObject:DistStr];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Say we have this array with stuff we want to iterate over and add those items to another array

```
NSArray *someArrayWithStuff = @[@"Hello",
                                @"Its",
                                @"Very",
                                @"Cold",
                                @"Outside",
                                @"Today"];
```

Say we want the content of someArrayWithStuff to be added to this other array so we create an NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *theNewArrayWithOurStuff = [NSMutableArray array];
```

We loop through the someArrayWithStuff

```
for (int i = 0; i < someArrayWithStuff.count; i++) {
    // Add object to the new array
    [theNewArrayWithOurStuff addObject:[someArrayWithStuff objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```